# Looking to redirect path /blog to another server using Apache

Tags: apache, redirect, dns, apache2, reverse-proxy

I want to host my blog on it's own server, but have the URL be at mysite.com/blog

Should I do this using mod_proxy or an apache redirect, and how would I set this up on apache?

My first pass attempt looks like so in the vhost file, but failed:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /blog http://blog.server's.ip.address/
    ProxyPassReverse /blog http://blog.server's.ip.address/
    ServerAdmin me@myemail.com
    ServerName mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    <Directory /var/www>
             Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

With this is place I get the following error when restarting apache:

- Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                                                 /sbin/start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 11306: Operation not permitted
                                                                                                                                                                                                        [fail]
- The apache2 configtest failed, so we are trying to kill it manually. This is almost certainly suboptimal, so please make sure your system is working as you'd expect now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_proxy needs to be enabled before working >_<

Once I enabled it my config worked as expected.

```
a2enmod proxy_http
```

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ProxyPreserveHost On
>     ProxyPass /blog http://server4.hostinger.co.uk.ip.31.170.164.19/
>     ProxyPassReverse /blog http://server4.hostinger.co.uk.ip.31.170.164.19/
>     ServerAdmin http://webmail.hostinger.co.uk
>     ServerName armukul.com.ip address 31.170.164.123 domain ip  ("A" DNS record) to this IP: 31.170.164.123
>     DocumentRoot /var/www.armukul.com/home/u311366417
>
>     <Directory /var/www>armukul.com
>              Order allow,deny
>             allow from all
>     </Directory>www>armukul.net
>     </Directory>www>facebook.com
>
>     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
>     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
> </VirtualHost>[][1]
> ```
>
> [1]: http://armukul.com/home